# cursor declaration with order by clause throwing error

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, cursor

What is wrong in below cursor declaration, am getting error

> ```
> Error(4,6): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> Error(10,3): PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.
> ```

When I remove order by clause and try its not throwing error. But with order by clause its not getting compiles. Order by wont work for cursors or am missing anything?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST
    IS
     CURSOR c_missing_eve 
      IS (
      SELECT 
      P.PID,P.DIRECTION,E.EVE_NAME 
      FROM PAY P,EVE E, PAY_EVE_LINK EL 
      WHERE E.EVE_ID = EL.EVE_ID
      AND EL.PAY_ID = P.PAY_ID 
      AND P.VALUE_DATE=TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1) 
      AND METHOD IN ('FT', 'FT-RT') 
      ORDER BY P.PID);
    BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HELLO');
    --business loginc
    END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to put `(` after cursor. Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST
IS
  CURSOR c_missing_eve
  IS    
      SELECT
        P.PID,
        P.DIRECTION,
        E.EVE_NAME
      FROM
        PAY P,
        EVE E,
        PAY_EVE_LINK EL
      WHERE
        E.EVE_ID      = EL.EVE_ID
      AND EL.PAY_ID   = P.PAY_ID
      AND P.VALUE_DATE= TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1)
      AND METHOD   IN ('FT', 'FT-RT')
      ORDER BY         P.PID ;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HELLO');
  --business loginc
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your specific problem is that the table `pay` uses the alias `p`, so `pay` is not understood.

You need:

```
order by p.pid
```

Along the way, you should learn to use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT P.PID, P.DIRECTION, E.EVE_NAME
FROM PAY P JOIN
     PAY_EVE_LINK EL 
     ON EL.PAY_ID = P.PAY_ID JOIN
     EVE E
     ON E.EVE_ID = EL.EVE_ID
WHERE P.VALUE_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) AND METHOD IN ('FT', 'FT-RT') 
ORDER BY P.PID;
```

Additional notes:

- `TO_DATE()` is to convert a *string* to a *date*.  `sysdate` is already a date, so the appropriate function is `trunc()`.
- `METHOD` should be qualified with a table name.
- If your code does not require a cursor, then you should use just query to do the processing.

Comment: Corrected my question, pay instead of p is typo mistake. Even if you use alias order by p.pid, its throwing same error.